# LINQ com múltiplos ON na condição OR?

Tags: linq, condição

Estou encontrando um problema na utilização do `LINQ`, não tenho muito conhecimento de como faz. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
(from BEN in repositorioBEN.RetornaTodos()
    join CON in repositorioCON.RetornaTodos() on BEN.Handle equals CON.Handle
    join APO in repositorioAPO.RetornaTodos() on CON.Apolice.Handle equals APO.Handle
    join PGD in repositorioPGD.RetornaTodos() on new
    {
        ben = BEN.Handle,
        con = CON.Handle,
        fam = BEN.Familia,
        est = APO.NroDoEstipulante,
        cor = APO.Corretor
    }
    equals new
    {
        ben = PGD.Beneficiario.Handle,
        con = PGD.Contrato.Handle,
        fam = PGD.Familia,
        est = PGD.HandleApolice,
        cor = PGD.Corretor
    }
    join TGE in repositorioTGE.RetornaTodos() on PGD.RegimeAtendimento.Handle.ToString() equals TGE.RegimeAtendimento
    where (PGD.DataFinal >= DateTime.Now && PGD.DataInicial <= DateTime.Now && BEN.Handle == idBeneficiario && TGE.Handle == idEvento)
    select new
    {
         QtdeDiasPagtoDiferenciado = PGD.QtdeDiasPagtoDiferenciado
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Na parte abaixo, preciso que essa condição seja `OR` e não `AND`.

Como devo fazer?

```
join PGD in repositorioPGD.RetornaTodos() on new
    {
        ben = BEN.Handle,
        con = CON.Handle,
        fam = BEN.Familia,
        est = APO.NroDoEstipulante,
        cor = APO.Corretor
    }
    equals new
    {
        ben = PGD.Beneficiario.Handle,
        con = PGD.Contrato.Handle,
        fam = PGD.Familia,
        est = PGD.HandleApolice,
        cor = PGD.Corretor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

não existe "OR" no join do linq, apenas o Equals, nesse caso você terá que fazer uma subquery no filtro para retornar os dados que precisa.